# Is it possible (and how to?) divide application to backend (admin part) and frontend (user part) parts?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am developing web application, using zend framework 2. In my app, I want some modules. News, for example, users etc.

Is it possible, to divide whole application to two big parts: front-end (for users) and back-end (for admins).

In front-end there will be part of News module, which render news list, full news item etc.
In back-end there will be part of News module, which will render list of all news, tools for editing, deleting etc.

At the moment, I have simple structure:

[image]

I have `MyZfcAdmin` module, with routes configurated so, that when I am writing `/admin/news/edit/5` it will call `NewsController` `edit` action with `id` 5 and render it. So now, I have all actions (for admins and for users) in one controller. Is it possible to create something like this:

```
module
    frontend
        News
        SomeMoreModule
    backend
        News
        SomeMoreModule
```

I found topic on google questions, in that suggested to use [this CMS](https://github.com/GotCms/GotCms), but I want to try it by myself.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from having an admin and a user route that both resolve to the same controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Different people have different idea in managing application, for me I will have news module that handle all news related calls both admin parts and user accessible parts. The idea you have described have some side effects like duplication of code between modules and crossing of borders between isolate modules like calling action in another modules(it's ok if there are related or fall in hierarchy), which may have issues in long term maintenance of the applications.

IMHO I might suggest you could create modules like News, users, etc where it can have combined functionality of both admin and user access. You can later include user authorization plug ins using bootstrap events and restrict action accessible by admin and other users

Answer (score 0):

There is not concept of submodules inside any module. But you can give them proper naming conversations. If code is not formed in oops properly, then there can be code duplication into your project. As per @raj's answer, it's good to give restrictions based on user role. If any action is not intersecting admin and user role then you can separate those actions, but actions like add or edit news content are same for both role then you should point to same action by router.